# Ember.js: Check if a record already exists in model ( Error - the adapter's response did not have any data)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

What I'm trying to do:
User will get error if user trying to register with username or email that are already registered in model.

When I tried to register with username(id) that is not registered, I got this error:
**`Error: Assertion Failed: You made a request for a user with id kevin, but the adapter's response did not have any data`** 
I'm debugging with console and reading documentation but I'm not sure why I get this error, please help me.

in the controller **`app/auth/register.js`**

```
var AuthRegisterController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  name:     null,
  username: null,
  email:    null,
  password: null,
  error:    null,

  actions: {
    register: function(){
      this.set('error', null);
      var userInfo = this.getProperties('name', 'username', 'email', 'password');

      ...

      if(this.store.find('user', userInfo.username)){
        return this.set('error', 'The username is already registered.');
      }
      if(this.store.find('user', {email: userInfo.email})){
        return this.set('error', 'The email is already registered.');
      }

      ...

    }
  }

});

export default AuthRegisterController;
```

User model structure : **`app/models/user.js`**

```
var User = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  password: DS.attr('string'),
  posts: DS.hasMany('post'),
});

User.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [{
    id: 'will',
    name: 'Will Smith',
    email: 'will@example.com',
    password: 'password'
  }]
});

export default User;
```

[Ember documentation - Finding Records](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/finding-records/)

Comment: take a look here https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1523 check what stefanpenner suggests, you'll need to implement something like that in your '.find's

Answer (score 1):

find is an asynchronous method, it will always return a promise immediately (aka all of those `if` statements will execute).  Using Ember Data for finding out if a record exists or not is overkill, and doesn't make sense.  It's a major flaw to return user information for a different user when they type in the username/email that's already in the system.  That's what Ember Data is used for, record management, not does this record exist.

All that being said, just create an endpoint on your server `/available_user` that allows you to post the username/email and it sends back a 200 with a results such as `{result:'ok'}` or `{result:'duplicate email'}` etc.

```
var store = this.store;
...
var request = $.ajax({
    url:'/available_user',
    type:'POST',
    data: getProperties
});

request.then(function(results){
  if(results.ok){
    record = store.createRecord('user', getProperties); 
    record.save();
  }
});
```

Comment: Oh I see, thanks a lot for the explanation! I haven't set up backend, I'm just using ember-cli, I'll set up backend and try again.